# Is it possible for me to export an animation as an OBJ File?

Tags: animation, export, obj

I have been reading around and cannot seem to find anything that will allow me to save a model animation as an OBJ file that would allow for CFD analysis in a different software. Any help on how to do this would be a great help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no OBJ does not support animations,

check more about all the specifications about .obj here:
http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/obj/

I suggest using FBX (.fbx) or Alembic (.abc)
for importing object with animations